# More than 8 lights without deferred shading / lighting

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to know if there is any technique (efficient) to use more than 8 lights in a scene made ​​with OpenGL and GLSL. Without making use of deferred shading / lighting.

I have not implementadon these techniques for their limitations and not being able to use transparency or antialiasing.

If there is a good alternative, describe it with an example.

I use OpenGL 2.0.

Comment: Fixed-function or programmable pipeline?

Comment: programmable pipeline (GLSL).

Comment: ...argh, reading comprehension fail on my part, sorry.

Comment: Multi-pass lighting (in your case, for whatever reason applying 8 lights per-pass) using additive blending. That is how it has been done since the dawn of time, deferred shading just changed it up so that you did not have to draw the geometry over and over on each lighting pass.

Comment: How efficient is relative to deferred shading / lighting?

Comment: Not very efficient at all for a large number of lights. The cost per-light is effectively the same, where as deferred shading has a high upfront cost to build and store the G-Buffers but then after that it is mostly just fill rate. Which approach is right for you depends on how many lights you want to apply and how much memory you have (less important these days on modern GPUs). I have to say though... usually you learn about this *before* deferred shading. Did you skip the basics?

Comment: Please do not [crosspost](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79505) on different stackexchange sites. View the discussion on crossposting [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the programmable pipeline, there really is no limit of 8 light sources. This limit only applies if you access pre-defined uniform variables like `gl_LightSource` in your GLSL code, and set them with fixed function calls of the `glLight*()` variety. In that case, you are indeed limited to `GL_MAX_LIGHTS` light sources, which is at least 8.

But instead of using the pre-defined `gl_LightSource` uniforms, you can easily define your own uniforms to pass the light source parameters you need for your lighting model into the shader. You define these parameters as `uniform` variables in your vertex shader (if you use per vertex lighting), and set them with `glUniform*()` calls in your code.

The limit you might encounter with this approach is the maximum number of uniform values. In the vertex shader, this is `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS` floats, which is guaranteed to be at least 512. That would give you 128 vectors. So if you need for example 2 vectors to describe each light source, that would give you 64 light sources. And most implementations will support much more than the minimum 512 uniform values.

Of course performance might be impacted by having more light sources. There are alternate approaches. For example, lighting can be pre-computed and stored in textures, e.g. in a cube map texture. Then instead of doing lighting calculations in the shader, you do a texture lookup.

Comment: I think you may be mixing up the OpenGL ES 2.0 limitation for maximum uniform components. In desktop GL the minimum value is 1024, which translates to 256 `vec4`s.

Comment: The latter you say seems interesting. What do you call that technique?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: I looked in the OpenGL 2.1 spec (glspec21.20061201.pdf, table 6.36, page 301).

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Ah, okay. The answer is specific to GLSL 1.20/1.10 then. The minimum value required for `gl_MaxVertexUniformComponents` has been 1024 since GLSL 1.30.

Comment: @JavierRamírez: Using a cube map to store the light is known as a "light probe."

Comment: I have also seen the term "light map" used for these kinds of methods.

Comment: Mmmmm, and this technique (light probe) is efficient with respect to deferred shading / lighting?

Comment: I do not think that you would call a cube map that does this a light map because cube maps are basically used to project the contribution of multiple light sources (essentially still doing the normal lighting equation, but replacing dozens of lights with a probe at one location), where as a light map is actually sampled on the surface itself with the pre-computed light. I have never seen a cube map used as a light map. I think we are thinking about two different things because of the introduction of cube maps.

Comment: MMM, it seems that I have to use after all deferred shading / lighting. Right?

Comment: Well, unless someone has something to add. To all thank you very much.

Comment: It really depends on what you're looking for. The main part of my answer explains how you can use a lot more than 8 light sources without using deferred lighting. That's the way I interpreted you original question.

Comment: Yes, but how good is this technique compared with deferred shading / lighting. Is it efficient?

Comment: There's really no general answer for which approach is faster. It depends on many factors. I wouldn't be too worried about having a moderate number of explicit light sources, particularly if you do per vertex lighting. But if you're pushing performance limits, and want to be confident that you have the fastest possible solution, there's really no way around implementing multiple options, and running comparative benchmarks for your specific use case. I know it sounds painful, but if the same approach were the fastest for all use cases, the other approaches wouldn't even exist.

Comment: All right. Thank you very much for you help, friend. :-)